# UIView Decorator Pattern Example

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, uiview, decorator

Can someone share an objective c UIView decorator pattern example. You may refer to the structure below.

Parent View with background

->Top bar view with background as child

->Content View with background as child

I was trying to create something similar to example from the book Pro Objective C Design Patterns decorator. Instead of a UIImage view I want to use a UIView and the example there is complex. If decorator doesn't apply please let me know.

I tried doing it myself but it seems the top bar overrides the parent view.

Comment: For not reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) I guess. StackOverflow is not a tutorial or resource site. Questions must represent a concrete programming problem that others can reproduce - include relevant source code, jsfiddle or whatever the issue's context is. This question is too general or lacks sufficient information to be properly answered. Hint - you can reword it by adding what you already tried and ask how to improve it.

Comment: I think the question is valid and clear enough. I dont expect a beginner to comprehend the question. Anyway I figured the answer myself. People dont read the manual. We could have figured that out in the first place and set strict validation before a post gets publish.

Comment: You could actually have posted the original code form the book and asked how to replace UIImage view with UIView. Do not expect everyone to have the book and know the example by heart. Make the question self-describing and thus useful to more people. Members of SO would appreciate some code to give hints on. Your question can really be on topic, but as it stands now, it looks more like asking for resources or code. Other people with the same problem might not recognize this as relevant to their issues. I am glad you found a solution though, and for sharing it.

Comment: (...continuing, max comment length reached) In your case the problem is not what but _how_ you ask. I hope you don't take any offense, as I am just trying to help you follow the rules and avoid asking questions that get flagged. This site has a giant user base, questions of low quality get asked _every minute_,  and moderators are really trying hard to keep it tidy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got to solve this problem.

First I created a header file where the protocol is.

```
@interface Window : NSObject
@end
@protocol Window <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)draw;
-(NSString*)getDescription;
-(UIView*)addView;
@end
```

Created a concrete window:

```
@implementation SimpleWindow
-(void)draw{
}

-(NSString*)getDescription{
    return @"simple window";
}

-(UIView*)addView{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 450)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
     return view;
}
```

Create a decorator/view feature/addon:

```
@implementation VerticalScrollBarDecorator
- (instancetype)initWithDecoratedWindow:(id<Window>)win
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        decoratedWindow = win;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)draw{  
}

-(void)drawVerticalScrollBar{   
}

-(NSString *)getDescription{
    return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[super getDescription], @"including vertical scrollbars" ];
}

-(UIView*)addView{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 450)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    UIView *superView = [super addView];
    [superView addSubview:view];
    return superView;
}
```

Implement it in viewDidLoad for instance:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    id<Window> decoratedWindow = [[VerticalScrollBarDecorator alloc] initWithWindow:[[SimpleWindow alloc] init]];
    decoratedWindow = [[HorizontalScrollBarDecorator alloc] initWithWindow:decoratedWindow];
    NSLog(@"%@", [decoratedWindow getDescription]);
    [self.view addSubview:[decoratedWindow addView]];
}
```

It will result to a main view with some views added as subview. There are many ways to achieve the same result but I want to maintain following the same pattern on Objective C because I also write in Java for Android. By the way, this is based on the Java example in Wikipedia.